# how can I pass a test in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I need to pass this test. In my test file I can't get results with tense "present" I'm just getting past "past" and "future" tense. In the case of present, 'assertion error' always appears.

```
    if tense == "past":
        verbs = ["drank", "ate", "grew", "laughed", "thought", "ran", "slept", "talked", "walked", "wrote"]
        verb = random.choice(verbs)
        return verb
    if tense == "present" and grammatical_number == 1:
        verbs = ["drinks", "eats", "grows", "laughs", "thinks", "runs", "sleeps", "talks", "walks", "writes"]
        verb = random.choice(verbs)
        return verb
    if tense == "present" and grammatical_number == 2:
        verbs = ["drink", "eat", "grow", "laugh", "think", "run", "sleep", "talk", "walk", "write"]  
        verb = random.choice(verbs)
        return verb 
    if  tense == "future":
        verbs = ["will drink", "will eat", "will grow", "will laugh","will think", "will run", "will sleep", "will talk","will walk", "will write"]
        verb = random.choice(verbs)
        return verb`
```

And here is the result in my test_sentence

```
def test_get_verb():
    verbs = ["drank", "ate", "grew", "laughed", "thought", "ran", "slept", "talked", "walked", "wrote"]
    for _ in range(4):
        word = get_verb(1, tense = "past")
        assert word in verbs

    verbs = ["will drink", "will eat", "will grow", "will laugh","will think", "will run", "will sleep", "will talk","will walk", "will write"]
    for _ in range(4):
        word = get_verb(1, tense = "future")
        assert word in verbs
```

Comment: There looks to be a bit of code missing here and it's not entirely clear what you're asking for.

Comment: @askman this is my entire code below and my task is Write a Python program that generates simple English sentences. During this lesson, you will write and test functions that generate sentences with three parts:

a determiner (sometimes known as an article)
a noun
a verb

Comment: @askman how can I send my code for you?

Comment: I assumed `def get_verb(grammatical_number, tense):` is the missing line and the test is passing. What is the problem?

Comment: @askan facebook or instagram?

Comment: @Leemosh Do you use Facebook?

Comment: @JoãoSilva this channel is here to help you, don't try to approach users to move to another platform
I'm still not sure what you're asking. You haven't included any code within your `tests_get_verb` function for present tense verbs

Comment: @JoãoSilva you can post it to your question (preferred way) and delete it later if you are scared of privacy.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/lojjEg

Comment: this is my test sentences https://codeshare.io/N3ZZkV

Comment: @JoãoSilva after copying your codeshares, all 3 tests are passing for me.

Comment: But in the test get_verb is just two tenses 'past' and 'future' all others times that I try pass 'present' tense appeared an error assert. It is missing the 'present tense'

Comment: Please ensure all code is placed into this post. Please avoid having incomplete code as it introduces difficulty to answer the problem (and others cannot learn from your question).

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you just mixed up the `grammatical_number`. If I use this, the tests pass.

```
import random

import pytest


def get_determiner(
        grammatical_number
):
    if grammatical_number == 1:
        words = ["the", "one"]
        word = random.choice(words)
        return word

    if grammatical_number == 2:
        words = ["some", "many"]
        word = random.choice(words)
        return word


def get_noun(
        grammatical_number
):
    if grammatical_number == 1:
        nouns = ["adult", "bird", "boy", "car", "cat", "child", "dog", "girl",
                 "man", "woman"]
        noun = random.choice(nouns)
        return noun
    if grammatical_number == 2:
        nouns = ["adults", "birds", "boys", "cars", "cats", "children", "dogs",
                 "girls", "men", "women"]
        noun = random.choice(nouns)
        return noun


def get_verb(
        grammatical_number,
        tense
):
    if tense == "past":
        verbs = ["drank", "ate", "grew", "laughed", "thought", "ran", "slept",
                 "talked", "walked", "wrote"]
        verb = random.choice(verbs)
        return verb
    if tense == "present" and grammatical_number == 1:
        verbs = ["drinks", "eats", "grows", "laughs", "thinks", "runs",
                 "sleeps", "talks", "walks", "writes"]
        verb = random.choice(verbs)
        return verb
    if tense == "present" and grammatical_number == 2:
        verbs = ["drink", "eat", "grow", "laugh", "think", "run", "sleep",
                 "talk", "walk", "write"]
        verb = random.choice(verbs)
        return verb
    if tense == "future":
        verbs = ["will drink", "will eat", "will grow", "will laugh",
                 "will think", "will run", "will sleep", "will talk",
                 "will walk", "will write"]
        verb = random.choice(verbs)
        return verb


def main():
    print(f"{get_determiner(1)} {get_noun(1)} {get_verb(1, 'past')}")
    print(f"{get_determiner(2)} {get_noun(2)} {get_verb(2, 'past')}")
    print(f"{get_determiner(1)} {get_noun(1)} {get_verb(1, 'present')}")
    print(f"{get_determiner(2)} {get_noun(2)} {get_verb(2, 'present')}")
    print(f"{get_determiner(1)} {get_noun(1)} {get_verb(1, 'future')}")
    print(f"{get_determiner(2)} {get_noun(2)} {get_verb(2, 'future')}")


main()


def test_get_determiner():
    # 1. Test the single determiners.

    single_determiners = ["the", "one"]

    # This loop will repeat the statements inside it 4 times.
    # If a loop's counting variable is not used inside the
    # body of the loop, many programmers will use underscore
    # (_) as the variable name for the counting variable.
    for _ in range(4):
        word = get_determiner(1)

        # Verify that the word returned from get_determiner is
        # one of the words in the single_determiners list.
        assert word in single_determiners

    # 2. Test the plural determiners.

    plural_determiners = ["some", "many"]

    # This loop will repeat the statements inside it 4 times.
    for _ in range(4):
        word = get_determiner(2)
        assert word in plural_determiners


def test_get_noun():
    # 1. Test the single nouns.

    single_nouns = ["adult", "bird", "boy", "car", "cat", "child", "dog",
                    "girl", "man", "woman"]

    # This loop will repeat the statements inside it 4 times.
    # If a loop's counting variable is not used inside the
    # body of the loop, many programmers will use underscore
    # (_) as the variable name for the counting variable.
    for _ in range(4):
        word = get_noun(1)

        # Verify that the word returned from get_noun is
        # one of the words in the single_nouns list.
        assert word in single_nouns

    # 2. Test the plural nouns.

    plural_nouns = ["adults", "birds", "boys", "cars", "cats", "children",
                    "dogs", "girls", "men", "women"]

    # This loop will repeat the statements inside it 4 times.
    for _ in range(4):
        word = get_noun(2)
        assert word in plural_nouns


def test_get_verb():
    verbs = ["drank", "ate", "grew", "laughed", "thought", "ran", "slept",
             "talked", "walked", "wrote"]
    for _ in range(4):
        word = get_verb(1, tense="past")
        assert word in verbs

    verbs = ["will drink", "will eat", "will grow", "will laugh", "will think",
             "will run", "will sleep", "will talk", "will walk", "will write"]
    for _ in range(4):
        word = get_verb(1, tense="future")
        assert word in verbs

    verbs = ["drinks", "eats", "grows", "laughs", "thinks", "runs", "sleeps",
             "talks", "walks", "writes"]
    for _ in range(4):
        word = get_verb(1, tense="present")
        assert word in verbs

    verbs = ["drink", "eat", "grow", "laugh", "think", "run", "sleep",
             "talk", "walk", "write"]
    for _ in range(4):
        word = get_verb(2, tense="present")
        assert word in verbs


pytest.main(["-v", "--tb=line", "-rN", __file__])
```

Assertion error is just that your assert is not passing and you are getting a lot of explanation why in the error message.

Comment: I copy this and don't pass for me. Appeared that message 'test_sentences.py:73: AssertionError: assert None in ['drinks', 'eats', 'grows', 'laughs', 'thinks', 'runs', '

Comment: I shared the code you sent (just in one file) and this is still working for me.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I copy the same of you shared and nothing happen just the same assert message error.

Comment: Now it should be working. I was testing the code and used wrong `grammatical_number`.   What do you think?

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention and help. Thank you so much! Have a nice day.